# Wordpress Permalink Structure in the Scheme of a Content Clustering Strategy?

Tags: seo, wordpress, links, permalinks

We're in the early stages of planning an information architecture rework with the goal of implementing a content clustering approach and a better internal linking strategy.

**What it looks like now:**
[image]

**Where we're headed:**
[image]

My question comes back to how folks are organizing Wordpress' permalink structure in order to maximize the effectiveness of cluster content when that content is a mix of pages and posts.

Using the often-used shoe example...  Let's say we've got a core page on our site about shoes (ex: www.ourfashionsite.com/shoes/). We may have a few sibling pages feeding that content silo (ex: www.ourfashionsite.com/shoes/jordans/).  We also likely have a number of blog posts about various shoe topics, currently permalinked using categories (ex: www.ourfashionsite.com/categoryname/best-heels-under-40-dollars/).

It seems we'd want to replace "*/categoryname/*" with "*/shoes/*" in the example above to funnel that cluster content back into our pillar content page (/shoes/), but since that url is used by the pillar content page, I'm confused about how to approach it with our extensive number of posts.